# How to iterate each User Profile with Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I've trying to iterate each User Profile with this snippet but at the following step:

```
write-host "Job Description for user" $User " is : " $up[$upAttribute].Value
```

the code always return the SuperUSer AccountName

```
$mySiteUrl = "http://MYsite"
#$adAccount = "DOMAIN\chill"
$upAttribute = "AccountName"
#$upAttributeValue = “http://get-spscripts.com”

#Get site objects and connect to User Profile Manager service
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)




function GetSPWebUsers($mySiteUrl) 
{ 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null 
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($mySiteUrl) 
    $web = $site.openweb() 
    $siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers 

    foreach($user in $siteUsers) 
    {        

        GetUserProfile($user)
        #if($user.IsSiteAdmin -eq $true) 
       # { 
           # Write-Host "ADMIN: ", $user.LoginName 
        #} 
       # else 
       # {  
           # Write-Host "USER: ", $user.LoginName 
        #} 
       # Write-Host " ------------------------------------- " 
    }    
    $web.Dispose() 
    $site.Dispose() 
} 



function GetUserProfile($User)
{ 


#Check to see if user profile exists
if ($profileManager.UserExists($User))
{
    #Get user profile and change the value
    $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($User)
    if(($up[$upAttribute].Value  -ne $null))
    {  

        Write-Host "Site Collection URL:", $mySiteUrl 
        write-host "Job Description for user" $User " is : " $up[$upAttribute].Value 
        Write-Host " ------------------------------------- "  

     }
     else
      {  
          #write-host "Job Description for user" $User
      }

   # $up.Commit()
}
else
{
   # write-host "Profile for user"$User "cannot be found"
}
#Dispose of site object
$site.Dispose()
}
```

> user DOMAIN\21000045  is :  DOMAIN\mossadm
>
> user DOMAIN\00006244  is :  DOMAIN\mossadm
>
> user DOMAIN\00003613  is :  DOMAIN\mossadm
>
> user DOMAIN\00000538  is :  DOMAIN\mossadm
>
> user DOMAIN\21002202  is :  DOMAIN\mossadm

Comment: try this one https://richardonsharepoint.net/2013/06/04/271/

Answer (score 0):

None of the prototypes of [UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.getuserprofile.aspx) take SPUser object as a parameter.

So, you may need to slightly modify your code:

Replace this code:

```
    $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($User)
```

With:

```
    $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($User.UserLogin)
```